# WP_safe_redirect not working

Tags: categories, wp-redirect

Instead of the project archives in my Divi theme being at `/project_category/[category name]/` I want them to go to `/portfolios/#[category name]`.

I modified the following code from [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160705/best-way-to-redirect-category-to-page-and-hide-category) and added it to my child theme's **functions.php** file.

```
function my_category_redirect()
{
    if ( is_category( ) ) {
        $category = get_queried_object();
        $cat_id = $category->term_id;
        $url = site_url( '/portfolios/#' . $cat_id);
        wp_safe_redirect( $url, 301 );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_category_redirect' );
```

However this is not working. The project categories are still going to `/project_category/[category name]/`. I can't tell if the **my_category_redirect** function is even being called.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action callback probably gets called, but it could be that the if-statement that just fails. Are you using the default "category" taxonomy (*i.e. Dashboard > Posts > Categories*) or a custom taxonomy (*i.e. Dashboard > {my-post-type} > {my-taxonomy}*) as the project category?

If you're using a custom taxonomy, then you should use [is_tax('my-taxonomy')](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/) instead of [is_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/) as the latter checks for the default category, not custom ones.

But, you can temporarily add a `die('it works');` to your callback also, before the if statement, to verify that it gets called.

Comment: Thanks @Antti_Koskinen, that fixed it!